# is my do loop code for java correct?

Tags: android, for-loop, usb, countdowntimer, batterymanager

is this correct?
im modifying a source code from github : USB CHARGE COMMANDER
when battery goes down from 20 percent it will charge
when batter goes 80 it wont
and countdown timer is for it to do this every 5 mins
i set 20000 just for testing

```
    boolean startcountdown=true;
    do{
         new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        Intent intent  = _context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));   
        int    level   = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        int    scale   = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
        int    percent = (level*100)/scale;

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

        public void onFinish() {
                if(percent <= 20){
                        _iIsCharging = 1;
                }
                else if (percent >=80){
                        _iIsCharging = 0;
                }
                else{
                        _iIsCharging = 1;
                }
            }
        }.start();
        }while(startcountdown);
```

Comment: You should alarmmanager for this sort of problem: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: im just a beginner at android dev and i dont know how to use and contruct those :(

Comment: Well you can read the tutorial and start learning here: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for this do/while loop to end, it's an infinite loop at the moment. The boolean "startcountdown" needs some way to eventually go to the value of FALSE. For example

```
if (_iIsCharging == 0) {
    startcountdown = false;
}
```

Comment: then what if i want to make it true again?
BTW its inside a switch case, the whole do loop

Comment: oh i have figured out how to do that TNX